# Show $r^n$ converges using squeeze theorem for $-1 \leq r \leq 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

How does this converge by squeeze theorem? I can see that if $0^x$ as x goes to infinity is = 0. But what about the otherside? How do we show that when $-1 \lt r \lt 0$, that r = 0 as x goes to infinity?

Comment: Why do you need any theorem, when it follows from definition? Fix $\epsilon >0$. Then $|r^n|<\epsilon$ for all $n>\frac{log\,\epsilon}{log\,|r|}$.

Comment: It's not true for $r=-1.$

Answer (score 1):

If we wish to use the squeeze theorem, then we can proceed as follows.

For $-1<r<0$, define $x>0$ such that $r=-\frac1{1+x}$.  Then, using Bernoulli's Inequality we have

$$0<|r^n|=\frac1{(1+x)^n}\le \frac1{1+nx}$$

Since $x>0$, application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(r^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges if and only if $$-1<r\leq 1.$$
To show this for $|r|<1$, consider $$|r^n-0|=|r|^n\to 0$$ because $|r|<1$. To prove this: for every $\varepsilon>0$, it is true that $|r|^n<\varepsilon$ for $$n>\log_{|r|}(\varepsilon).$$ There is no need for the squeeze theorem; although you could say that $0\leq|r^n|=|r|^n$ is "squeezed" by $0$ and $|r|^n$, both converging to $0$.

Now, for $r=1$, this is just the constant sequence ($1$), so it converges.

For $r=-1$, this is the alternating sequence $(-1)^n$, which is not convergent.

For $|r|>1$, the sequence is unbounded, so it is not convergent.